# Generating an object model in Ruby from an XML DTD

Tags: xml, ruby, dtd

I have an XML document with a DTD, and would love to be able to access the XML model, something like this:

```
title = Thing.Items[0].Title
```

Is there a way, in Ruby, to generate this kind of object model based on a DTD? Or am I stuck using REXML?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why all the answers assume Rails.  Is that indicated in the question?

Comment: XmlSimple is a part of Rails, but it's not dependent on Rails. You can install it into Ruby without installing all of Rails by using `gem install xml-simple`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ruby version of xml-simple.

You shouldn't need to install the gem as I believe it's already installed with rails.
http://xml-simple.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 2):

if you include the active_support gem (comes with rails) it adds the method from_xml to the Hash object.  You can then call Hash.from_xml(xml_content) and it'll return a hash that you can use to access the data.

I don't know of an easy way to map an xml to an object, but you could create a wrapper class that delegates the method calls to the underlying hash which holds the data.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was asked a while back, but if you want the true Thing.Items[0].Title type format, all you need to do is use OpenStruct.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'activesupport' # For xml-simple
require 'ostruct' 

h = Hash.from_xml File.read('some.xml')
o = OpenStruct.new h
o.thing.items[0].title
```

Comment: Ha, too funny.  I Googled this question, thought I liked this answer, decided that this was a good solution, copied the code, ran a test, realized that's the way I wanted to go, came back to close the tab, and then realized that I was the one who left this answer a year and a half ago.